# How to hide the text with css ellipsis and show all text when there is enough space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm almost very close to what I need, but still, some parts don't work as to how I want it to be.

So I have created one row with four columns using Bootstrap 3, of course, I'm free to use some additional CSS classes that could help me. Now if you take a look at the result - Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yz04va3c/

In the fourth column the part of the title is hidden using CSS properties such as:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

It works ok when you observe it in the large screen, you should see four columns, now if you resize to a medium or small screen, you will see that according to the width of the browser window, two or one column will take the entire space of the row. Even though the space is sufficient enough to display all text in the title, it is still for some reason hidden with the dots I mean ellipsis style.

What I need is to display all text in the title if there is enough space there, so on two or one column in this provided example, it should show all the text without hiding anything.

The responsible part of the HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="text-center" style="max-width: 250px;">
   <h3 class="lora-font font-bold text-center" style="font-size: 1.5em;">
      <div style="width: 99%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Asun „Nat snack“</div>
   </h3>
</div>
```

The problem here I feel is that the max-width is set to 250px so it's a fixed width, but how I would go about making it not fixed, like I need some kind of way to make it work in percentages, but I'm not sure if this is a hacky way to do it or there is a much simpler way to do this thing? All I tried is playing with width property and percentages, but it looks like my approach is not the proper way to do it.

Any help would be really appreciated if you can think of some alternative way or what else I could try because using fixed units I feel is not going to work well.

Comment: Sorry I just provided the wrong js fiddle url, I immediately updated the link.

Comment: I tried the text-overflow in your fiddle without the max-width and it worked fine. I can't see your problem here

Comment: Yeah, removing max-width actually works, can't believe I didn't observe this myself. But it looks like I have other side effects on my website, I feel that some other parts are interfering with it, even thought I tried as best as I could provide just the code that is needed. Really tricky situation. But thank you, I now will try to find out why the column width gets bigger on my website if I remove max-width.

Comment: So I removed max-width from all the columns https://ibb.co/TbWVxW1 but on the fourth column where the title is the longest column looks bigger and way off, I mean it's not the same width and height as other three columns.

Comment: I really thank you for your comment because even until now I wouldn't have been come to this point, so the problem was with the <div class="container"></div> which was wrapping my row and columns. And there was a property max-width: 1200px; thats why didn't get the same width for all the columns.

Comment: No problem, as long as your problem is fixed